# How can I setup sam-cli to launch an Alexa skills lambda for testing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, aws-sam-cli

I can't seem to figure out how to get a functioning Alexa skills lambda function running locally. Using `ngrok` Amazon properly connects to my running sam container, but all I get is a `POST /` that results in a 404.

I copied a sample from the AWSLABS sam repo for Alexa:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: Demonstrates a basic skill built with the Amazon Alexa Skills Kit.
Parameters: 
  TopicNameParameter: 
    Type: String
Resources:
  alexaskillskitcolorexpert:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      CodeUri: .
      Description: Demonstrates a basic skill built with the Amazon Alexa Skills Kit.
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 3
      Policies:
        - SNSPublishMessagePolicy:
            TopicName: !Ref TopicNameParameter
      Events:
        AlexaSkillEvent:
          Type: AlexaSkill
```

Answer (score 2):

Alexa Skills can connect to two different types of backend.  It can be an AWS Lambda Function or any [HTTPS exposed web services](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-a-web-service.html).  You are trying to mix both, this is why your sample code is not working.

When a skill is hosted as an HTTPS endpoint, [it has to provide extra code](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-a-web-service.html#requirements-for-web-service) that is not required when using AWS Lambda inetgration with Alexa Skills.  For example, the Alexa service will send signed requests over HTTP POST that your skill must reply to. On the other hand, when hosted as an AWS Lambda function, there is no signature required, as the AWS Lambda trigger mechanism ensures that only the Alexa Service can call your skill code.

The example you downloaded exposes the code as an AWS Lambda function and creates a Lambda trigger to authorise the Alexa service to call your function.  This is the line here :

```
Events:
        AlexaSkillEvent:
          Type: AlexaSkill
```

But when you are exposing your code running locally through `ngrok`, you are switching to the other model : custom HTTPS endpoints.  So, the Alexa service expects your code to answer the `POST` requests it is sending over which the example does not do.

I would suggest to not use `ngrok` to test your Alexa skill exposed as a AWS Lambda function.  Only use `ngrok` if you plan to test code to be deployed as an Alexa Skill custom HTTPS endpoint.

To test your code locally, you can use unit test frameworks, such as [mocha](https://mochajs.org/) for NodeJS.   The idea is to capture the requests sent by Alexa in the Alexa developer console or your Lambda logs and to replay it locally on your laptop.

Here is an example I wrote to test my skill using this technique : https://github.com/sebsto/maxi80-alexa/tree/master/lambda/test

You also can use third-party testing frameworks, such as [bespoken](https://bespoken.io/).  Here is another example I wrote to show how to use bespoken for local unit test : https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-audio-player/tree/mainline/single-stream/test/unit

Comment: I think I get what you posted, much appreciated. I found my way into the project `bespoken` as well. I figured I wanted to learn this SAM stuff. What would be required to allow my local sam started lambda to function with the HTTPS endpoint? This is obviously not going to be used for production of any kind -- not even for other beta testers. It would just greatly simplify and accelerate my iterations. (for my first skill I found incredibly annoying, even with the askcli, to make a single stmt change and deploy over and over and over. >>)

Comment: I do not recommend to start with the awslabs example, they are old and not using the latest Alexa Skill SDK. There is a lot of boiler plate code to be written.  Have a look at the Alexa Skill Command Line instead, this will boostrap a new project in minutes.  https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/quick-start-alexa-skills-kit-command-line-interface.html  I know it does not answer your ngrok question.  I will try to find time today to build an example.  The idea is to write code to handle the HTTP request your will receive when running locally

Comment: And to use an HTTP framework (such as Express) to route requests to code.  This code shows an example https://github.com/JennJin/alexa-sdk-express-ngrok/blob/master/server.js (it is based on the old Alexa SDK with `this.emit()` don't use that) but the purpose is to show how to use express to handle HTTP requests and route to your code)

Comment: Fantastic! I will take a peak tomorrow during some downtime. Thanks for tracking this issue.